Nuxt 3 ssr custom error page (404) not showing in production mode
I have a code below
error.vue
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <div class="prose">
        <template v-if="error.statusCode === 404">
          <h1>404!</h1>
          <p>Sorry, that page doesn't exist.</p>
        </template>
            <template v-else-if="error.statusCode === 500">
              <h1>500!</h1>
                <p>
                  <strong>{{ error.message }}</strong>
                </p>
      </template>
    </div>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>


<script setup>
const error = useError();
</script>

This works fine when in dev mode (when entering wrong path it displays 404 error), but when project is built and uploaded to cloudflare pages, when entering wrong path it displays 500 error instead

it's not static page, but ssr. Also I feel like you used AI to get the answer.
